# Declare a variable in type that includes Generic

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I am trying to declare a variable and define it's type:

```
const state: State<A, B, C> = { ... };
```

I am getting the following error: `Cannot find name 'A'.`
It looks like TS thinks I am using a type A that already defined, but what I want is something like that:

```
const state<A, B, C>: State<A, B, C> = { ... };
```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: I don't think you can use generic type placeholder for a type/class when declaring a variable.
Type placeholders can be used only when you're declaring `class`/`function` not when you're using it.

Comment: So what are my alternatives to define the type of that variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a factory function, like:

```js
interface State<A, B, C> { 
  a: A,
  b: B,
  c: C
};

function createState<A, B, C>(obj: State<A, B, C>) {
  return obj;
}

const state = createState({
  a: "abc",
  b: 2,
  c: true
});
```

Another option is to replace the interface by a class:

```js
class State<A, B, C> {
  constructor(
    readonly a: A,
    readonly b: B,
    readonly c: C
  ) {}
}

const state = new State("abc", 2, true);
```

Comment: Create a function to create the initial value, it's not efficient and looks weird. But if this is the only option, this might be the solution I'll use...

Comment: Unfortunately, if you work with an interface, it's the only way to force the compiler to infer generic types. Another option is to replace the interface by a class. I've added the sample to my answer too.